# How to open and read a property file with Argparse

Tags: python, json, python-3.x, python-2.7, properties-file

I got stuck on this python program, that reads a file using Argparse argument. Somehow it gives me the error "no such file & directory" while reading a property file (`application-DEV.properties`). But I can see the file is available in the code Repository. Below is my code.

Command to execute:

```
python create_param_store.py --Tier DEV
```

Python Code:

```
def load_envproperties(sep='=', comment_char='#'):
    
    props = {}
    with open("../../../src/main/resources/application.properties",'rt') as f:
        e=set(f.readlines())
        
    with open("'../../../src/main/resources/application-' +  pa.Tier + '.properties'", 'rt') as f:
        d=set(f.readlines())
        for line in list(d-e):
            l = line.strip()
            if l and not l.startswith(comment_char):
                key_value = l.split(sep)
                key = key_value[0].strip()
                value = sep.join(key_value[1:]).strip().strip('"') 
                props[key] = value
                print(props[key])
                putssm(Name=key, Value=props[key])
            
        
def init():
    global pa
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description='Additional Params.')
    parser.add_argument('--Tier', nargs='?', dest='Tier', required=False, help='Tier')
    pa = parser.parse_args()
```

Error:

```
 File "create_param_store.py", line 59, in main
    load_envproperties()
  File "create_param_store.py", line 38, in load_envproperties
    with open("'../../../src/main/resources/application-' +  pa.Tier + '.properties'", 'rt') as f:
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: "'../../../src/main/resources/application-' +  pa.Tier + '.properties'"

[Container] 2020/08/30 21:37:42 Command did not exit successfully python create_param_store.py --Tier $Tier exit status 1
[Container] 2020/08/30 21:37:42 Phase complete: BUILD State: FAILED
```

Comment: This is a typo, you have double quotes around your single quotes, but still expect the code inside to work. Use one type of quotes, properly escape, or use f-strings.

Comment: Thanks Grismar. I tried to change as defined but this time it gives syntax error ```File "create_param_store.py", line 38
    with open(''../../../src/main/resources/application-' +  pa.Tier + '.properties'', 'rt') as f:
                 ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax```

Comment: You still have quote issues in that string. Why is there `''` (a double single quote) at the start and end? I recommend getting an editor or IDE that assist in avoiding these very basic problems (which are just typos, mis-writing the basic syntax of the language) like PyCharm, Syder or VSCode (to name but a few).

Comment: As well as the quote issues, the (intended) hard-coded directory `../../../src/main/resources/` will be relative to the process's current working directory. Is this really the intention, or did you intend to use a path relative to the location of the script? Hint: the directory containing the script will be `os.path.dirname(__file__)`.